# "NUM DISTINCT" in Oracle Column Properties

Tags: database, oracle

There are various properties linked with columns in an table, like ID, PK, NULL?, Data Type, etc.

What is the sense of NUM DISTINCT property associated. I am unable to get the use of it.

A column may have distinct values, but still, what is the sense of '16' being the value under NUM DISTINCT property of a primary key.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is used by the optimiser. In short : as the value of num_distinct (in relation to num_rows) increases the use of an index will get more desirable.

Comment: So does value of 'Num Distinct' tell us how many distinct values are in this column?

Comment: Yes https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm#BEICJFIG